# Resonance Soundfield Recorder

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, resonance-audio

I'm using the Resonance Audio Listener script to capture resonance audio sources in my scene. It's currently only recording audio to channels 1 and 4 (with silence on 2 and 3). Does anyone know what could be causing this? Everything else seems to be working fine. On Unity 2017.3.1f1. Could a newer version of resonance fix this? I'm not sure what version of that I'm using. Thanks

Update: I was using timeline to trigger animations, which remain static when the resonance recorder is activated. A friend was able to edit the code to enable the sound field recorder to work during runtime and everything is recording properly now.

Comment: Hi Michael, out of curiosity, since in Ambisonics, channels 2 & 3 are left-right, up-down respectively are your source(s) in front / at the back of the listener by any chance?

Comment: There are audio sources all around (including left and right).

Answer (score 0):

Unity has released patches that fix a [related issue](https://github.com/resonance-audio/resonance-audio-unity-sdk/issues/14), which caused 2017.2.1f1+ to not use Resonance Audio for spatialization. Try 2017.3.1p1 to see if that fixes things.

https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases

Comment: Updated to Unity 2017.3.1p4 and the latest resonance SDK and still having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry to hear that didn't work. I see you posted to GitHub; hopefully our engineering team or the developer community can help resolve.